# Linq to Entity data model

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Am trying to write a very simple select statement like below using Linq against Entity data model

trying to achieve

`"Select * from SAPCostcentre where costcentermanager="mike";`

Created my edmx and add a new class to write my DAO like below using linq but it doesn't like it.

```
public void ResourceCollection(string CostCenter)
    {
        string name = "Mike";

        var context = new ScheduALLDAL.SAPCostCentre();
        var query = from c in context.CostCentreManager where      context.CostCentreManager = name select c;
        var costcenter = query.ToList();        


    }
```

It throws exception "can not convert type string to `bool` here "context.CostCentreManager = name"

in my db design `costcentermanger` data type is `varchar`. Please some one throw me a light what am missing here or the right approach .

Comment: Wild guess.. try context.CostCentreManager == name.. because context.CostCentreManager = name doesnt make it boolean.

Comment: what kinda idiot i am ? thanks a lot guys. some one advise please ,this is the right approach to write the linq queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `==` as you are making a Boolean evaluation. The rest of your code should be OK then :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you need to use a double equals sign (==).  By using a single equals sign you are trying to assign context.CostCentreManager to "name".

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
 var query = from c in context.CostCentreManager 
      where context.CostCentreManager == name select c;
```

use `==` instead of `=`

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from c in context.CostCentreManager 
    where context.CostCentreManager == name 
    select c;
```